# Number of times word appears

Tags: python, string

I  have to create a function that takes two lists. The first is a list of words like `["tant", "", "you"]` and the second list has `["hi", "something", "both", "sporte "]`. I want a dictionary with the number of times the words of the first list appear in the second.

My code gives me the opposite i.e., gives me the number of times the words of the second list appears in the first.
This is my code:

```
from collections import Counter    
    timesmumber def (x, y):            
         number = x
         dicitio = Counter (number)
         return dict (dicitio)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with `list.count` method :

```
>>> l2=["hi", "something", "both", "sporte "]
>>> l1=["tant", "", "you","hi"] 
>>> {i:l2.count(i) for i in l1}
{'': 0, 'you': 0, 'tant': 0, 'hi': 1}
```

If you want to check for prefix you can use `sum` function instead of `count` :

```
>>> l1=['some', 'tant', '', 'you', 'hi']
>>> l2=['hi', 'something', 'both', 'sporte ']
>>> {k:sum(1 for j in l2 if k and k in j) for k in l1}
{'': 0, 'hi': 2, 'you': 0, 'tant': 0, 'some': 1}
```

Comment: this does not work,when i use in the first list "bot" it is not in the second one like"bot" in "botlane" for exemple.what i need is the prefixes

Comment: @Lusokid sorry i don't understand what you mean? can you add this explain with a example to your question?

Comment: what I want is to know the number of prefixes that appear in the second list, ie the first list has words / prefixes and perciso to know the number of times these prefixes appear in the second as "some", "something"> >> some; 1

Answer (score 4):

so given that you have a list

```
first_list = ['tant', '', 'you']
```

and a second list

```
second_list = ['hi', 'something', 'both', 'sporte', 'tant']
```

you can create a dictionary with a built in `count` method

```
{nr : second_list.count(nr) for nr in first_list}
```

Comment: thanks!! but how can i transform that into a cicle? the :{nr : second_list.count(nr) for nr in first_list}

Comment: btw this does not work,when i use in the first list "bot" it is not in the second one like"bot" in "botlane" for exemple.what i need is the prefixes